# How to add a hyperlink to a multiline element in a table, which uses makecell?

Tags: tables, hyperref, multirow, makecell

I've an existing table in LaTeX (for my resume), which uses `makecell` package to produce the formatted output in multiple lines for each entry. Example of one row:

```
2007 & \makecell[c] {Bachelor of Engineering in\\ XYZ Engineering}   
     & \makecell[c] {A.B.C \\ University, PQR} 
     & 80\%  \\
```

I'm trying to embed a hyperlink (so that clicking on the name of the Institute would take the reader to the corresponding webpage) using the `hyperref` package. So, I tried this (for each line) :

```
2009 & \makecell[c] {Master of Technology in\\  Computer Science}
     & \makecell[c] {\href{http://www.xyz.ac.in/}{XYZ Institute\\ RST}}     
     &  90\% \\
```

But I'm getting errors as follows:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
\endgroup
```

What am I doing wrong ? Also, is it even possible to have a multi-row entry pointing to a single link (or do I have to either make it a single row first, give the link separately etc)?

Comment: Put the argument in a minipage or parbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the cell contents in the second argument of `\href`:

```
2009 & \makecell[c] {Master of Technology in\\  Computer Science}
     & \href{http://www.xyz.ac.in/}{\makecell[c]{XYZ Institute\\ RST}}
     & 90 \\
```

Comment: ...or `\makecell[c]{\href{http://www.xyz.ac.in/}{XYZ Institute}\\RST}` to just hyperlink `XYZ Institute`, since `\href` can't have `\\`.

Comment: egreg's solution worked fine for me...I didn't try the other ones.